# How can I tune the optimization function with Keras Tuner?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-tuner

How can I tune the optimization function with Keras Tuner? I want to try SGD, Adam and RMSprop.

I tried:

```
hp_lr = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
hp_optimizer = hp.Choice('optimizer', values=[SGD(learning_rate=hp_lr), RMSprop(learning_rate=hp_lr), Adam(learning_rate=hp_lr)])

model.compile(optimizer=hp_optimizer,
              loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

but this doesn't work as "A `Choice` can contain only one type of value"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best way is to do something like this:

```
hp_optimizer = hp.Choice('optimizer', values=['sgd', 'rmsprop', 'adam'])

if hp_optimizer == 'sgd':
    optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=hp_lr)
elif hp_optimizer == 'rmsprop':
    optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=hp_lr)
elif hp_optimzier == 'adam':
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=hp_lr)
else:
    raise

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Obviously you'd want a more descriptive exception (or just leave it since it should never occur anyway). Even if the different optimizers were of the same class, IIRC `hp.Choice` only allows ints, floats, bools and strings, so I don't see a way around doing it like this.

Answer (score 2):

The question was answered a long time ago, but maybe someone will need an alternative solution that is working in my setting.:

```
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', 
                                 values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4]
                                 )
    optimizers_dict = {
        "Adam":    Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
        "SGD":     SGD(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
        "Adagrad": Adagrad(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate)
        }

    hp_optimizers = hp.Choice(
        'optimizer', 
        values=["Adam", "SGD", "Adagrad"]
        )

    model.compile(
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer=optimizers_dict[hp_optimizers],
        metrics=[
            AUC(curve="ROC", name="roc"),
            AUC(curve="PR", name="pr"),
            Precision(name='precision'),
            f1_score
            ]
        )
```